# Flutter Firebase IOS: Red dot on Appicon

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

my IOS Flutter App shows after receiving an firebase notification a red dot (5 unread messages) on my app icon. But when you click on the notification there are still 5 unread notifications. This problem is only on IOS not on Android.

The class notificationservice contains every function for fcm.
Do someone have a clue?

main.dart:

```
    Future<void> newApp() async {

      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await AppChecker.checkAppStatus();
      if (OckData.FCMcheckExecute) {
    
        await  Firebase.initializeApp();
        firebaseNotificationService fs = firebaseNotificationService();
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('news');
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('tester14');

        
        await fs.firebaseMain();

      }
      


        await FirebaseMessaging.instance
          .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true,
        );

        NotificationSettings settings = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
          alert: true,
          announcement: true,
          badge: true,
          carPlay: false,
          criticalAlert: false,
          
          provisional: true,
          sound: true,
       );
    
    runApp( const MyApp());
  }
```

notificationservice.dart:

```
class firebaseNotificationService {

  late FirebaseMessaging messaging;
  

  firebaseNotificationService (){
    if (OckData.FCMcheckExecute) {      
      messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    }

    
  }
  

  Future<String?> getToken () async{
    if (OckData.FCMcheckExecute) {      
      return await messaging.getToken(
        vapidKey: OckData.firebase_webpush,
      );
    }


  }

  listenMessage () {

      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {


        
      });
    }

  }

 
  firebaseMain() async {
    if (OckData.FCMcheckExecute) {
      RemoteMessage? initialMessage = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

      // If the message also contains a data property with a "type" of "chat",
      // navigate to a chat screen
      if (initialMessage != null) {
        OckData.initinalRout = '/post';
        if(initialMessage.notification!.title == null){
          OckData.postTitle = 'FEHLER: Nicht erkannt';
          OckData.postId = '38';//initialMessage.data['body'];
        }
        else{
          OckData.postTitle = initialMessage.notification!.title.toString();
          OckData.postId = initialMessage.data['body'];
        }

      }

     
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingNewHandler);
      FirebaseMessaging.instance
      .getInitialMessage()
      .then((value) => value != null ? _firebaseMessagingNewHandler : false);
      
      
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_firebaseMessagingNewHandler);
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async{

       return await _firebaseMessagingNewHandler (message);
      });

      

      
    }
  }


}

void postselect (String postid, String betreff){
    
    Abos abo = Abos ();
    NavKey.navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed('/post', arguments: [postid, betreff]).then(abo.onGoBack);
}





Future<void> _firebaseMessagingNewHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {

  if (OckData.FCMcheckExecute) {   

    String title = '';
    String id = '';
    if(message.notification == null){
      title = 'FEHLER: Nicht erkannt';
      id = message.data['body'];
    }
    else{
                    print(message.data['body']);

      title = message.notification!.title.toString();
      id = message.data['body'];
    }

    OckData.initinalRout = '/initinalStart';
    postselect(id, title);
  }
}


Future<bool> checkInitinalMessage () async {
  RemoteMessage? initinalMessage = await getInitialMessage();
  if(initinalMessage!=null){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }

}

Future<RemoteMessage?> getInitialMessage () async {
  RemoteMessage? initialMessage = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

  return initialMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself: The red dot is called badge. And in my Server Script there was the argument badge = 5 by sending the notification (in the curl request).

```
'notification' => array(
  'title' => $title,
  'body' => $message,
  'content_available' => "true",
  'sound' => 'default',
  'data' => $id,
  'badge' => '5'
 ),
```

Comment: can you tell me how to add badges in flutter app, because i try lots but not working in my android app, using vivo android device.

Comment: You can using firebase cloud messaging. This is a google Service for Push Notifications. Then you can use the badge attribute like in my code above. Otherwise I need more information about your project, to help you.

Comment: Yes, i am using firebase messaging but for badges i was tried in demo app which have no firebase messaging, for that demo app i was used package flutter app badger but is not working. asper you code i think no need to used any extra package for red dot. for your reference of my code please see this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75415201/how-to-open-different-different-screen-onclick-on-push-notification-for-flutter